# How to programmatically add child with zPosition to scene created with Scene Editor

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm having trouble controlling the zPosition of a node. If created on the scene editor I have no problem, but later when I want to add a new node with code, the zPosition is not respected.

```
//GameScene
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    super.didMove(to: view)

    let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
    circle.zPosition = -1
    self.addChild(circle)
}
```

This circle would for example appear in front of a node created on the Scene Editor with zPosition 100

Answer (score 0):

two things:

1) Im not entirely positive but I'm almost certain zPosition has to be a positive integer

2) if you want it to appear in front of a node with z position 100 than that z position has to be a number > 100

so either

```
circle.zPosition = 101
```

or

```
circle.zPosition = (name of what u want circle to appear in front of).zPosition + 0.1
```

Comment: zPosition can be negative,  it needs to be allowed since it is relative to parent